# What is the purpose of this onKeyDown Event Function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found this code in a project and I am not sure what is the purpose of it. It is passed in the `onKeyDown` event to an editable div. Is this function doing anything useful or can I remove it?

```
stopEditing = (event) => {
    let keys = {
        backspace: 8,
        shift: 16,
        ctrl: 17,
        alt: 18,
        delete: 46,
        leftArrow: 37,
        upArrow: 38,
        rightArrow: 39,
        downArrow: 40,
    }

    let utils = {
        special: {},
        navigational: {},
        isSpecial(e) {
            return typeof this.special[e.keyCode] !== 'undefined'
        },
        isNavigational(e) {
            return typeof this.navigational[e.keyCode] !== 'undefined'
        },
    }

    utils.special[keys['backspace']] = true
    utils.special[keys['shift']] = true
    utils.special[keys['ctrl']] = true
    utils.special[keys['alt']] = true
    utils.special[keys['delete']] = true

    utils.navigational[keys['upArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['downArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['leftArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['rightArrow']] = true

    let hasSelection = false
    let selection = window.getSelection()
    let isSpecial = utils.isSpecial(event)
    let isNavigational = utils.isNavigational(event)

    if (selection) {
        hasSelection = !!selection.toString()
    }

    if (isSpecial || isNavigational) {
        return true
    }
}
```

Editable Div:

```
<div
    tabIndex="0"
    contentEditable="true"
    suppressContentEditableWarning="false"
    onKeyDown={this.stopEditing} // This is the function
    onInput={this.onChangeHandler}
    onKeyPress={this.preventEnterKey}
/>
```

Comment: That code is used to restrict what keys can/cannot be pressed when the contenteditable div is focussed. Whether that's any use to you or not, none of us can tell you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is the function above preventing any keys from being pressed then? As far as I can understand, it is not doing anything because I am able to press all the keys mentioned in the function and the ones that aren't mentioned as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function ckeck if the pressed key is one from the list let

```
keys = {
        backspace: 8,
        shift: 16,
        ctrl: 17,
        alt: 18,
        delete: 46,
        leftArrow: 37,
        upArrow: 38,
        rightArrow: 39,
        downArrow: 40,
    }
```

There are three different keyboard events in JavaScript:

`keydown`: Keydown happens when the key is pressed down, and auto repeats if the key is pressed down for long.

`keypress`: This event is fired when an alphabetic, numeric, or punctuation key is pressed down.

`keyup`: Keyup happens when the key is released.

---

**Update :**

i think this function is for disable key event for keys that not found on this keys list but i think it need to return false in the last like this

```
stopEditing = (event) => {
    let keys = {
        backspace: 8,
        shift: 16,
        ctrl: 17,
        alt: 18,
        delete: 46,
        leftArrow: 37,
        upArrow: 38,
        rightArrow: 39,
        downArrow: 40,
    }

    let utils = {
        special: {},
        navigational: {},
        isSpecial(e) {
            return typeof this.special[e.keyCode] !== 'undefined'
        },
        isNavigational(e) {
            return typeof this.navigational[e.keyCode] !== 'undefined'
        },
    }

    utils.special[keys['backspace']] = true
    utils.special[keys['shift']] = true
    utils.special[keys['ctrl']] = true
    utils.special[keys['alt']] = true
    utils.special[keys['delete']] = true

    utils.navigational[keys['upArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['downArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['leftArrow']] = true
    utils.navigational[keys['rightArrow']] = true

    let hasSelection = false
    let selection = window.getSelection()
    let isSpecial = utils.isSpecial(event)
    let isNavigational = utils.isNavigational(event)

    if (selection) {
        hasSelection = !!selection.toString()
    }

    if (isSpecial || isNavigational) {
        return true
    }
    return false

}
```

Comment: Ok. But then the value returned from the `stopEditing` function is not being used anywhere right? It just returns true or false, but this true and false value is not making any difference on the editable div, right?

Comment: I added the `return false` line but it still doesn't do anything different. Can you check that please? 

From what you have explained, I think this function has no intended purpose in the project so I will remove it. Thank you for explaining!

Comment: I would make one edit in your answer. It seems that returning true or false in this function does not make a difference (Other than preventing the lines after the return statement from being executed). To prevent keys from being pressed, one must use `event.preventDefault()`